# POSTGRES : SELECT : Query for number of rows which EXIST BETWEEN given range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to query the table to search for given conditions :

1. order_no specified in the range must exist.

   Example:  I am getting a request for a range of order_no: 003 - 007. So, I want to check whether all the order_no mentioned in range exist or not.If not exist return false.
2. The order_status of ALL order_no must be 1. If not exist return false.

   `Order_string    Order_no   Order_status
       ABE              1                1
       ABE              2                1
       ABE              3                0
       PSB              4                0
       PSB              5                1
       PSB              6                0
       REL              7                0
       REL              8                1
       REL              9                1
       REL              10               1`

I was trying EXIST and BETWEEN but unable to query the DB.

Comment: if you have a parameter of "all" what is the "range"?  I think your question is missing some information

Comment: @Used_By_Already I have edited the description. Is it seems correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check these conditions:

```
count(order_no) = count(distinct order_no) -- order_no are distinct in the range
and count(*) = end_val- start_vat+ 1 -- number of rows equals to size of the range
and bool_and(order_status::bool) -- all order_status are 1
```

The first condition is not necessary if the column is unique.

You can do this in the function:

```
create or replace function check_range(int, int)
returns boolean language sql as $$
    select 
        count(order_no) = count(distinct order_no)
        and count(*) = $2- $1+ 1
        and bool_and(order_status::bool)
    from my_table
    where order_no between $1 and $2;   
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you want a false if at least one of the `ORDER_STATUS` for `ORDER_NO` between 3 and 7 is 0

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Z.SUM_STATUS > 0 THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS RESULT
FROM    
    (SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN (ORDER_NO BETWEEN 3 AND 7) AND (ORDER_STATUS = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_STATUS
    FROM YOUR_TABLE) Z;
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:** You can use this concept, if it will return 1 then `TRUE` else `FALSE`

```
SELECT 1 
FROM tmp t
WHERE Order_no BETWEEN 003 AND 007
    AND Order_status = 1
HAVING COUNT(*) = (007-003)+1
```